# Using Multiple Initializers in Upgradable Smart Contract

Tags: openzeppelin, hardhat, upgrading, contract-upgrading

For Upgradable Smart contract following pattern as specified here:

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable#avoid-initial-values-in-field-declarations

"Constructor"/Initializer has form:

```
function initialize() public initializer {
       .......
       .......
       .......
    }
```

Now suppose I have a set of initial value field declarations and I set them in a separate initializer - say:

```
function initializeInitialValues() public initializer {
       .......
       .......
       .......
    }
```

The code below does not pick up the initializers

```
let MyContract;
let mycontract;

describe("MyContract", function() {

  beforeEach(async function () {
     MyContract= await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract");
     mycontract= await upgrades.deployProxy(MyContract, {initializer: 'initialize', initializer: initializeInitialValues()});
  });
       .......
       .......
       .......

});
```

Using only `await upgrades.deployProxy(MyContract, {initializer: 'initialize'}`  and putting all values in there works. i.e

```
function initialize() public initializer {
       constructor values
              &
       initial value field declarations
    }
```

**When deploying/testing the smart contract how do I specify multiple initializers?**

Especially as a means to logically separate unrelated components in the upgradable smart contract. i.e. constructor values vs initial value field declarations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone else wondering about this, see this response: [OpenZeppelin Forum](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/using-multiple-initializers-in-upgradable-smart-contract/13849/6)